# Definability of truth in $L$ without $0^{\#}$

Tags: set-theory

Cross-posted to MO at commenter's suggestion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269303/definitional-complexity-of-truth-in-l-without-0

I'm writing some expository notes about $0^{\#}.$ I'm trying to explain what makes it so remarkable (excuse my pun). To me, what makes it interesting is that truth in $L,$ which goes way into the infinite, can be encoded by a real defined using only real number quantification. But I don't know if this necessitates the existence of $0^{\#}.$

My advisor showed me an argument that you don't need $0^{\#}$ for truth in $L$ to be definable (he showed me a model without $0^{\#}$ where cardinals $\kappa$ such that $L_{\kappa} \prec L$ are precisely those where GCH fails). Of course, this definition requires quantification over the set-theoretic universe.

So my question is, how low complexity can a definition of truth (without parameters) in $L$ be if $0^{\#}$ doesn't exist? Can there still be a definition with only real quantification? Could it even be $\Delta^1_3?$

Comment: You might consider cross-posting this on MathOverflow.

Comment: The argument is interesting. Do you have a reference, or at least what are the starting assumptions? (I'd guess something like cut the universe at a Mahlo or weakly compact cardinal, or something like that?)

Comment: Yeah he assumed a Mahlo $\kappa,$ forced GCH to fail at inaccessibles below $\kappa$ with $L_{\kappa} \prec L,$ and then cut the universe at $\kappa.$ (My description above isn't exact but it's the idea).

Comment: * $L_{\alpha} \prec L_{\kappa}$